# Difference between event bus and event aggregator?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, prism

I'm just starting out with WPF and Prism and I'm learning about event aggregators. My first question regarding all this is: what is the difference between event bus and event aggregator?

It sounds like MS fluff - which to be fair is a common issue in the Practices namespace! Is it just an event bus with an MS name? kinda like when they took dependency injection and renamed it policy injection for absolutely no apparent reason?

w://

Comment: not sure if that analogy holds, or any of that last paragraph is more than rant over naming - event aggregator is the name of a pattern. They implemented it by the name EventAggregator. How clear can that be? 'Policy Injection' on the other hand is the name of the Application Block in ENTLib, and that does more than just plain simple DI. So they gave it another name. On the other hand, MS also supply basic DI frameworks, one called MEF and another Unity, and they do call it Dependency Injection there, no fluff.

Comment: ref this http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/07/22/braindump-on-the-event-aggregator-pattern/